# What does the percentage output represent in RWeka M5P (tree model) output?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, weka

I have been teaching myself how to use RWeka, specifically so that I may implement the M5P model. I have been able to use apply to my data, but do not understand what the percentage represents. For example, the beginning of the sample output from RWeka's manual is:

```
M5 pruned model tree:
(using smoothed linear models)

CHMIN <= 7.5 : LM1 (165/12.903%)
```

The other LMs have other "scores" like this, like (6/18.551%) and (23/48.302%). What exactly do these percentages and numbers represent?

Also, if they do not represent the accuracy or success of the predictions, then how can I access such a value? I'm thinking about the correlation coefficient classically shown in machine learning papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The percentage is the root relative squared error. I figured this out by using the summary() function in R on my model.